# Karhunen Loeve Transform(KLT) for random image on python

Tags: python, opencv

Good morning. I want apply a KLT on python for one random image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Lenna_(test_image).png', 0)

eigenVal, eigenVec = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(img))

column = []

for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    column.append(img[:, x])

y = eigenVec.T * (column - np.sum(img) / img.shape[0])

klt = np.dot(eigenVec, img)

cv2.imshow("klt", y) # 1° solution
cv2.imshow("KLT", klt) # 2° solution
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I just want to know if the process is right.

Thanks.